# iOS adding variable to label's text

Tags: ios, variables, nsstring, uilabel

I've been working on an iOS app and I've run into some complications in one of the screens.

This screen, titled "about", has just 2 labels: they're supposed to display the current username and time.

The labels' text loads well but I can't get them to show me the variables with the username and the current time.

Here is my code:

**About.h**

```
@interface About : UIViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * username;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * date;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * usuari;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * data;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * currentTime;
```

**About.m**

```
#import "About.h"

@interface About()
@end

@implementation About

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel * username = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(162, 106, 150, 72)];
    [self.view addSubview: username];
    username.text = @"Usuari: ";
    username.numberOfLines = 4;
    username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Usuari: ", _usuari];

    UILabel * date = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 261, 1488, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview: date];
    date.text = @"Hora: ";
    date.numberOfLines = 4;
    date.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hora: ", _currentTime];

}

-(void) gettingUser
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    self.username.text = self.name;
}

-(void) gettingTime
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    self.date.text = self.currentTime;
    //self.date.text = [NSDate date];

    //NSTimer schedule interval
    //NSDateFormatter alloc
}


@end
```

Can you help me figure out what do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the variable are not showing is due to no format specifiers. I'm also surprised you didn't receive compiler warnings or errors with the above code.

This line of code:

```
 username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Usuari: ", _usuari];
```

Should be written, like this - not so?

```
    username.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Usuari:%@ ", _usuari];
```

As `_usuari` is the variable and the `%@` is the format specifier, of where you want to place that variable.

After this: `ursername.text` should print out like so: Usuari: *variable value*

Comment: @user3082271 Xcode would definitely show an issue with the original code due to the mismatch in the format string and the arguments. Don't ignore such information.